# How do I switch from npm to yarn in my project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, maven, npm, yarnpkg

I'm having an issue trying to switch to yarn from npm inside my project. I tried downloading yarn and I'm still getting npm to start my project. I need to switch because a project I'm working on needs it to be yarn so I can add a maven frontend plugin to tie my backend and frontend to gather for deployment.

[image]

```
1.
<frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.6</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
<node.version>v10.13.0</node.version>
<yarn.version>v1.12.1</yarn.version>

2.
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>demo</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>src/js</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install node</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                                <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>yarn install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>yarn</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>yarn test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>yarn</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>test</arguments>
                                <environmentVariables>
                                    <CI>true</CI>
                                </environmentVariables>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>yarn build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>yarn</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>build</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-resources</id>
                            <phase>process-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/js/build</directory>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Link1
https://github.com/amigoscode/spring-boot-react-fullstack/blob/app-0/course-files/profiles.txt
Link2
https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Full simple step-by-step answer:

1. Install yarn `npm i -g yarn`
2. Go to directory where u install packages and run `yarn` command
3. Yarn will init and create its `yarn.lock` file, now delete `package-lock.json` *`* Note`*
4. In your `package.json` file replace in `"scripts"` all `npm` commands for `yarn` *`** Note`*
5. Run `yarn dev` or whatever command u use for running a yarn script **=>** **DONE**

*`* Note:`* it is important you don't delete it before `yarn` command (as some people suggest) it can break things, for example your `yarn` command will not even work and it will throw error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './package-lock.json'
```

*`** Note:`* If you used

```
 "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
```

you can remove it, yarn is taking `"resolutions"` by default without a need for force :)

Comment: In a step 3 I said `you can delete package-lock.json` but you actually `must delete it` since it can clash with `yarn.lock` I had problem with it before on `Netlify` - it wouldn't build/deploy with both files in project folder.

Answer (score 22):

It's quite simple; follow those instructions:

1. Verify that `Yarn` is installed on your machine globally, else use `npm install -g yarn` to install it.
2. Go to your root project directory and type `yarn` on your CLI; `Yarn` can consume the same `package.json` format as npm, and can install any package from the npm registry.

For more details, check the [official yarn doc](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/).

Comment: In that case can i delete package-lock.json file?

Comment: of course, you could. Yarn lock file will be created automatically.

Comment: As of Yarn 1.7, you can also just use `yarn import` and it will attempt to replicate the same dependencies found in package-lock.json.

Answer (score 6):

You need not to do anything to switch from npm to yarn as long as yarn is installed in your Computer. Also to install packages using yarn, you should run the command `yarn` rather than `yarn install` which is equivalent to `npm install`. Because yarn is nothing stand alone library. Yarn is only a new CLI client that fetches modules from the npm registry. Nothing about the registry itself will change — you’ll still be able to fetch and publish packages as normal.

For more information about yarn you should read [This](https://www.sitepoint.com/yarn-vs-npm/)

Comment: Wrong, you cannot use yarn and npm in the same time. Some servers even crash build when they see `package-json.lock` and `yarn.lock` in the same time (experienced that with Netlify). I suggest following my step by step answer.