# TypeError: Ajv is not a constructor when I run npm run build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, build, ajv

I'm stumbling on an error every time I run `npm run build`

error:

```
/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:66
const ajv = new Ajv({
            ^

TypeError: Ajv is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ts34mpr/website/client/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:66:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ts34mpr/website/client/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/index.js:6:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
```

please does anyone knows the solution or can help please!
Thank you

Comment: I just came across the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: nope... in fact I re-initiated the project and copied all components then it worked, but this solution is just for building the project locally not on the server

Comment: I also have the same problem after updating version of `Node.js+npm` 
(before I was updating `CRA` and weback to version 5) but it was broken by the Node.js version update.

Comment: `We decided to move from npm to yarn` due to many issues recently with `npm` - also since this error was `unfixable` in 1MD and we needed to release new production asap. How to move from npm to yarn I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71481424/6027872

Comment: Solution was to migrate from npm to yarn as following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71481424/6027872

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to migrate from npm to yarn as following: [stackoverflow.com/a/71481424/6027872](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71481424/6027872)

Answer (score 4):

Same problem for me. I find if I delete node_modules and package-lock.json and then run `npm install` and `npm run build`, that solves it. Not a great answer. I'd like to know the real solution.

Comment: Had the same issue and as the answer states, it worked for me. IIRC this occurred after a nodejs upgrade.

Comment: deleting `package-lock.json` can break things don't do that on any occasions (maybe unless you are the only one working on the project and it's not production app, but still its not recommended solution)

Answer (score 4):

I have a more permanent answer than my previous one. Downgrade mini-css-extract-plugin to 2.4.7. For example:

```
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.4.7",
```

I tested each version from 2.5.3 down and this is most recent version where this error does not occur.

It would be nice to know *why* this works, but it does.

Comment: Does not work for me, usually is peer dep but even fixing it by `resolutions` doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

add resolutions to the package.json.

```
"resolutions":{
   "mini-css-extract-plugin":"2.4.5"
}
```

then run  `npx npm-force-resolutions` in your terminal.

I was able to solve the issue with this.