# 'npm start' Taking way too long

Tags: reactjs

Whenever I run 'npm start' in VsCode as a react app, it is taking about 30 seconds However I have friends that have a slower computer than me and it is taking about 5 - 10 seconds. What might be the issue here? Is there a command or library that will make 'npm start' faster? Thanks in advance!

This is my package.js file:

```
{
  "name": "m_city",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "d3-ease": "^3.0.1",
    "firebase": "^9.6.10",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-awesome-reveal": "^3.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-move": "^6.5.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-app-rewired-esbuild": "^0.0.10"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-scripts/eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends on what `npm start` does for your app.

Comment: for my app this is what `npm start` does: ` "start": "react-scripts start", `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it depends on how you create yours react app.
You can use `yarn` or `npx` instead of `npm`.

Solution 01

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Here `npx` will search for if your package already exists locally or globally, if not found `npx` will install your package.

Solution 02

You can also use `yarn` this is actually an alternative to `npm`. You just have to install `yarn` globally.

```
npm install --global yarn
yarn create react-app my-app
cd my-app
yarn start
```

After that you can install any packages faster than before by using `yarn` for example:

```
yarn add firebase
```

Comment: wait so if I add yarn globally, do I have to change anything with my project code itself or can I use `yarn start` instead of `npm start`

Comment: Follow this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64197841/15497939

Answer (score 0):

change another terminal. I use ubuntu to start npm, it takes about 5mins but when I use git, it's just 30s and I don't know why

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem also, I just move to another terminal and everything now takes less then 5 seconds, try **git bash**.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal open new terminal by selecting 'arrow down' next to the '+' and choose git bash. Then run 'npm start' again. Git bash is faster.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).